# How to write user data directly into MS Word created CV Template?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I created CV Templates in MS Word.
Fed them into an Android App.
If a user selects a CV Template a Copy of it will be generated.
Then User will enter data and it will directly fill the CV Template and positioned data according to template automatically.
The Problem is, How can User's entered data directly replace the CV Template's data and positioned accordingly.

Comment: Can you post all your relevant code you have written so far?

Comment: Firstly, Thanks to edit and I have written nothing yet. I just completed prototyping.